# "I have nothing about which to think"

Tags: prepositions

If sentences like

> I have something to eat.

are translated as

> Mi havas ion por manĝi.

as it would be in French, then what about sentences like

> I have something **about** which **to** think.
>   I have nothing **onto** which **to** jump.

That is to say, is the "por" still necessary here?

> Mi havas ion, pri kio [por] pensi.
>   Mi havas nenion, sur kion [por] salti.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the English phrases also sound really unnatural, even though they might be technically grammatically correct. I would say “I have something to think about”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need the *por* anymore, nor would it even be right to add it in, in my opinion.

```
Mi havas ion, pri kio pensi.
Mi havas nenion, sur kion salti.
```

Of course, you can also rephrase if you prefer:

```
Mi havas ion, pri kio mi povas pensi.
Mi havas nenion, sur kion mi povas salti.
```

The English sentences here are somewhat misleading, I think, because the *to* in the last two examples I think is different from the *to* in the first example. In the first example, it's a particle meaning something like 'in order to'; in the later examples, it's just a particle introducing the infinitive. Given that, you can see that English is actually not that different here, either.